# Как написать шаблон функции для вычисления размера массива C++

Tags: c++, массивы, шаблоны-с++

Не могу разобраться в том, как это реализовать, приведите, пожалуйста, код такого шаблона.

Answer (score 4):

Ну, например...

```
template<typename T, size_t N>
size_t dim(T (&)[N]) { return N; }

int main()
{
    int x[4];
    double t[] = {1,2,3};

    cout << dim(x) << endl;
    cout << dim(t) << endl;
}
```

Шаблонная функция, которой передаем ссылку на массив (имя неиспользованного параметра я не стал и указывать). При инстанцировании она выводит значение `N`, каковое и возвращает...

Comment: size_t N>
size_t dim(T (&)[N])

Comment: Что происходит в этой строке?

Comment: пожалуйста, добавьте пояснения к коду